# Robocopying DLLs and EXEs

Tags: robocopy

I've used Robocopy for several years now for backup purposes, and never looked back at any backup application I used in the past.

I replicate whole valued directories to a removable HD, than from this HD to and equivalent system.

Over time, quite a few DLL and EXE have accumulated in these directories, none of which Robocopy can seem to copy to my external HD.  Thus, my 2 computers drift apart slowly...

Is there anyway, using one of the eigthy-nine (89) switches (or one of the 2^89 - 1 = 6,1897002 × 10^26 combinations thereof) to force Robocopy to robotically copy EXEs, DLLs and other of my "access is denied" friends?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing better than a coffee in the morning and 2 downvotes to start a brand new day :-)  I did search about my (small) problem, in an out of Server Fault, and looked at the cursive robocopy manpage (\B: Backup mode. Ah yes, and how about \ZB?  Well, it does the Z, then the B if Z fails).  Frankly, downvoting without an explanation is equivalent in my book to drive-by shootings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`/B : Copy files in Backup mode.`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. There was a permission problem using the \B switch on a scheduled task, but checking "Run whether user is logged on or not" and "Do not store password" in the task definition solved that.  I'm wondering now if copying the DLLs and EXEs just needed both of these options to run properly, since the error message was exactly related to access priviledges.